# ASP.NET Core 8 OpenTelemetry

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, open-telemetry

I have a following OpenTelemetry configuration in my ASP.NET Core 8 code (it pushes logs and metrics to Application Insights on Azure):

```
builder.Services
       .AddOpenTelemetry()
       .UseAzureMonitor(x => x.ConnectionString = configuration.AppIns.ConnStr)
       .ConfigureResource(builder =>
            {
                builder.Clear();
                builder
                    .AddService(serviceName: "MyService1", serviceInstanceId: Environment.MachineName);
            })
       .WithMetrics(builder => {})
       .WithTracing();
```

And in my classes I use logs like that:

```
public class MyClass1
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyClass1> _logger;

    public MyClass1(ILogger<MyClass1> logger)
    {
        // ...

        void Method() 
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("test1");
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that in logs I don't see the class name (with namespace), nor the file path where the log was logged. In other words, how to see `MyClass1` in Application Insights CustomDimensions.

Comment: This isn't an OpenTelemetry issue. You wouldn't see those things no matter what logging infrastructure was used. Whether you use the Console logger or Serilog, the file location isn't included in log events so can't appear in log messages.

Comment: Besides, you configure OTEL *tracing*, not logging in your code. Traces are generated from ActivitySource and Activity. You need to use `builder.Logging.AddOpenTelemetry` to also send logs to an OTEL target

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 1) but I do see the traces in AppInsights. CustomDimensions contain machine name. Logs or traces whatever :) AppInsights interests me 2) With Serilog in .net 6 it did work. I had SourceContext in customdimensions

Comment: Serilog is a different logging library with its own enrichers.  Ultimately they created their own patterns to work around limitations in tracing at the time. I'm sure you could build out the same system, however ultimately the better approach is to embrace tracing instead of logs for those usecases.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow a simple steps

1. Implement middleware with `logger.BeginScope()` to get a machine name or whatever you need..
2. Than you implement filepath and calssNames or whatever you need in AppLogger wrapper
3. Use logs with messages how you need

Middleware sample code:

```
public class LoggingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public LoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ILogger<LoggingMiddleware> logger)
    {
        using (logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object> { ["MachineName"] = Environment.MachineName }))
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}

// In Startup.cs or Program.cs, depending on your project's setup
app.UseMiddleware<LoggingMiddleware>();
```

Custom AppLogger:

```
public class AppLogger<T>
{
    private readonly ILogger<T> _logger;

    public AppLogger(ILogger<T> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void LogInformation(string message, [CallerFilePath] string filePath = "")
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"{typeof(T).FullName} [{filePath}]: {message}");
    }

    // Implement other logging methods (LogDebug, LogError, etc.) as needed
}
```

Example usage in your application:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly AppLogger<MyClass> _logger;

    public MyClass(AppLogger<MyClass> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Doing something important.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Since there are no other answers I've granted Bounty here. But I think there must be a better way, np by BaseProcessor. Yet I hoped it's built-in.

Comment: @andrew.fox Im not aware of better solution. This is how we handle it in our company...